# .NET Core / Kubernetes - SIGTERM, clean shutdown

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core

I'm trying to verify that shutdown is completing cleanly on Kubernetes, with a .NET Core 2.0 app.

I have an app which can run in two "modes" - one using ASP.NET Core and one as a kind of worker process.  Both use Console and JSON-which-ends-up-in-Elasticsearch-via-Filebeat-sidecar-container logger output which indicate startup and shutdown progress.

Additionally, I have console output which writes directly to stdout when a SIGTERM or Ctrl-C is received and shutdown begins.

Locally, the app works flawlessly - I get the direct console output, then the logger output flowing to stdout on Ctrl+C (on Windows).

My experiment scenario:

- App deployed to GCS k8s cluster (using `helm`, though I imagine that doesn't make a difference)
- Using `kubectl logs -f` to stream logs from the specific container
- Killing the pod from GCS cloud console site, or deleting the resources via `helm delete`
- Dockerfile is `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime` and has `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAppHere.dll"]`, so not wrapped in a `bash` process or anything
- Not specifying a `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` so guess it defaults to 30 sec
- Observing output returned

Results:

- The API pod log streaming showed just the immediate console output, "[SIGTERM] Stop signal received", not the other Console logger output about shutdown process
- The worker pod log streaming showed a little more - the same console output and  some Console logger output about shutdown process
- The JSON logs didn't seem to pick any of the shutdown log output

My conclusions:

1. I don't know if Kubernetes is allowing the process to complete before terminating it, or just issuing SIGTERM then killing things very quick.  I think it should be waiting, but then, why no complete console logger output?
2. I don't know if console output is cut off when stdout log streaming at some point before processes finally terminates?
3. I would guess that the JSON stuff doesn't come through to ES because filebeat running in the sidecar terminates even if there's outstanding stuff in files to send

I would like to know:

- Can anyone advise on points 1,2 above?
- Any ideas for a way to allow a little extra time or leeway for the sidecar to send stuff up, like a pod container termination order, delay on shutdown for that  container, etc?

Comment: did you try to increase terminationGracePeriodSeconds?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov I just tried it with a value of `60`.  I still get the same output, but I note that it doesn't take 30/60 seconds.  I still have all the same questions unfortunately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGTERM` does indeed signal termination.  The less obvious part is that when the `SIGTERM` handler returns, everything is considered finished.

The fix is to not return from the `SIGTERM` handler until the app has finished shutting down.  For example, using a `ManualResetEvent` and `Wait()`ing it in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

I've started to look into this for my own purposes and have come across your question over a year after it was posted... This is a bit late, but have you tried [GraceTerm](https://github.com/OleConsignado/graceterm)?
There is an associated [NuGET package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Graceterm/) for this.

From the description...

> Graceterm middleware provides implementation to ensure graceful shutdown of AspNet Core applications. The basic concept is: After application received a SIGTERM (a signal asking it to terminate), Graceterm will hold it alive till all pending requests are completed or a timeout occur.

I haven't personally tried this yet, but it does look promising.

Answer (score 1):

Try add `STOPSIGNAL SIGINT` to your Dockerfile

Comment: Could you add a **brief explanation** on how it is supposed to resolve the problem described in the question ? Keep in mind that answers that contain an explanation are considered to be of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.